# Is there a way to load local csv.gz file in huggingface dataloader?

Tags: huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I'm using `datasets` library by huggingface to load csv dataset stored locally. The problem is, the dataset is compressed and is stored as a `csv.gz` file. Therefore, I'm not able to load it using `load_dataset('csv', '<local_file_path>.csv')` method in huggingface.

Answer (score 0):

Just decompress it with gunzip:

```sh
gunzip -v yourdataset.csv.gz
```

Comment: So, that means NO?

Comment: @MahavirI: At the moment the answer is no. Loading a `csv.gz` leads to an error on my machine (the hard disk is filled with GB of cache files even if the file is very small. Smells like a bug.).